Curse of dimensionality in Time series with K-means
I have been looking at the following notebook: time series clustering 
where the writer says that the dataset is affected by the "Curse of Dimensionality", so applying TimeSeriesKMeans offered by tslearn is not correct. Instead, PCA  is applied to the column "values" of the time-series to get just 2 components out of the time-series values and then a normal k-means function is used to divide into clusters.
I have been looking online and it seems that the Curse happens only when the dataset has many features and few data. The dataset in the article has only 2 features (timestamp, value) and many data, so in my opinion, there is no "Curse of dimensionality", hence doing the PCA on all the "value" columns is useless.
Am I missing something important?
On the other hand, if the article is right, every time I want to study a time series I may apply PCA on all the values and then use the classic k-means, instead of the TimeSeriesKMeans function offered by tslearn
